# Lubuntu 20.04 LTSでbashを使っていますが、renameコマンドを使うとエラーが出ます。

Tags: ubuntu, bash

**現象**
Lubuntu 20.04 LTSのbashに`apt-get`でrenameコマンドをインストールしました。そして、ファイルの拡張子が.shになっているものを、拡張子が.txtになるように下記のコマンドを実行したところ、エラーが出ました。

```
$ rename .sh .txt *.sh
syntax error at (user-supplied code), near "."
```

また、`.`をつけずに実行してみたところ、`Bareword ~`のメッセージが出ました。

```
$ rename sh txt *sh
Bareword "sh" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (user-supplied code).
```

**期待値**
`.sh`のファイルの拡張子をすべて`.txt`に変換したいです。

**再現手順**

```
$ sudo apt-get install rename
$ rename .sh .txt *.sh
$ $ rename sh txt *sh
```

Comment: 要件から察するに、`rename` パッケージに含まれる `rename` コマンド(perl 実装)ではなく、`util-linux` パッケージに含まれる `rename.ul` コマンドの方が適切かと思われます。

Comment: `man rename` や `rename --help` などでコマンドのシンタックス (使い方) を確認するのも一つの方法だと思います。

Comment: @metropolis `rename.ul`コマンドのほうが確かに適切でした。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @cubick アドバイス感謝です！次からやってみますね！

Answer (score 1):

```
rename 's/\.sh$/.txt/' *.sh
```

で変換できると思います。

Comment: 承知しました。やってみます。